# How to extract required data from CURL response?

Tags: php, curl

Here is the response I am getting. I just want to extract **access_token**. How can I do this. Please help.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Via: 1.1 lvqma554 (), 1.1 lvqma554 () 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Connection: keep-alive 
X-CorrelationID: Id-e41cc17c551ba0be17900000 0; Id-9a8a03a2551ba0be02907400 0 
Cache-Control: no-store 
Date: Wed, 01 Apr 2015 07:39:42 GMT 
Pragma: no-cache 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
X-AMEX-DPG-DEPRECATED: No 
X-AMEX-DPG-MSG-ID: Id-e41cc17c551ba0be17900000 
X-AMEX-DPG-STATUS: Success 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{ 
    "access_token" : "7612126f-dea3-449b-b349-94be115e938a",
    "token_type" : "mac", 
    "expires_in" : 7200, 
    "refresh_token" : "bc17169d-4fa0-407f-976f-32b2b4ef8812", 
    "scope" : "card_info",
    "mac_key" : "537d3fc2-6a86-456a-b38b-60f77fe79a45", 
    "mac_algorithm" : "hmac-sha-1" 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a json string:

```
$a = '{ "access_token" : "7612126f-dea3-449b-b349-94be115e938a", "token_type" : "mac", "expires_in" : 7200, "refresh_token" : "bc17169d-4fa0-407f-976f-32b2b4ef8812", "scope" : "card_info", "mac_key" : "537d3fc2-6a86-456a-b38b-60f77fe79a45", "mac_algorithm" : "hmac-sha-1" }';
$b = json_decode($a,true);//here the json string is decoded and returned as associative array
echo $b['access_token'];
```

Yields:

```
7612126f-dea3-449b-b349-94be115e938a
```

Answer (score 1):

The response you're getting is JSON.

To work with it in PHP you need to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) it.

This will return an object with the data from the json response.

The code would be

```
//getData
$obj = json_decode($jsonString);
echo $obj->access_token; //Will echo out the value
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is referring to curl (and I assume you mean the command line tool) but your post is tagged as a php question. The latter part has already been answered, but maybe you still need a command line version (using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)):

```
curl "https://<your-url>" | jq '{ .access_token }'
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is on JSON format: http://json.org

JSON (Javascript Object Notation) is a special key/value format useful on HTTP Requests or Payload Share between Javascript and Server Side.

I think you have to use json_decode to get data, but you have to check always if the payload response is in the right form.

You could do this:

```
$jsonResponse = '{ "access_token" : "7612126f-dea3-449b-b349-94be115e938a", "token_type" : "mac", "expires_in" : 7200, "refresh_token" : "bc17169d-4fa0-407f-976f-32b2b4ef8812", "scope" : "card_info", "mac_key" : "537d3fc2-6a86-456a-b38b-60f77fe79a45", "mac_algorithm" : "hmac-sha-1" }';
//getData
$obj = json_decode($jsonResponse, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

if(! $obj || ! isset($obj->access_token) {
   echo "Error with the data.";
} else {
   echo $obj->access_token; 
}
```

In general, if you want to know if a string is a valid JSON or not, i can suggest to use this: https://www.jsoneditoronline.org
It's very useful for JSON debugging.

Let me know if you need help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an all in one JSON tool like [JSON Viewer, formatter and validator](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) to load JSON data from a url, upload a file from your desktop or copy and paste JSON data into the tool. This tool will also validate, format and minify JSON data.

Comment: I think the question is about extracting the `access token` programmatically, you don't need a tool to extract the `access token` manually