# cant get values from returned string in CURL with cakephp

Tags: php, json, curl, cakephp

I simply have a returned string? from CURL and cannot get the values like access_token? I am using cakephp 4 (we have debug not var_dump)

Code in cakephp (same as php)

```
 $AccessToken = $this->CreateAccessToken($jwt);
 $token=json_decode($AccessToken);
  debug($token);
 debug($token['access_token']);
```

> 

The string appears like below from the debug this but I can't extract the values. The issue I believe is the json_decode isnt working so i still get the string

```
/////////////////
debug($token) :        { "access_token": "Bearer exxxxxxxxxx1h7kQuxaOqB-AbaoMPh7qLgA", "expires_in": 1892160000, "api_domain": "https://xx1.xxh.com/v1", "token_type": "Bearer" }

debug($token['access_token']:Notice (8): Trying to access array offset on value of type int
/////////////
```

Thats what appears above on var_dump of debugs. I can display the whole returned token but i cant access anything inside it

here is the code that does that

```
private function CreateAccessToken($jwt)
{
$jwt_token = "Bearer ".$jwt;
$headers = array("content-type: application/json", "Authorization:".$jwt_token);

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://xx/v1/xx/api/token",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
    'assertion' => $jwt_token,
    'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer')),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if($err) 
    {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
      return 0;
    } 
    else 
    {
      return $response;
    }
}
```

output var_dump($token)//still a string in an int?

```
{ "access_token": "Bearer exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2GB3PS5c4tq9iOvSTH7lx-7gI_JHaw", "expires_in": 1892160000, "api_domain": "https://xx.xx.com/v1", "token_type": "Bearer" }int(1)
```

output var_dump($AccessToken)//still a string in a bool?

```
 { "access_token": "Bearer eyxxxxxxnx1bul67sSWM8fxFmLkJywP6UZryO9o8", "expires_in": 1892160000, "api_domain": "https://xx.xx.com/v1", "token_type": "Bearer" }bool(true)
```

[How to extract required data from CURL response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385427/how-to-extract-required-data-from-curl-response)

Comment: _"string appear like below from the debug"_ - if that output appeared based on that debug statement - then it makes no sense, that you would get the mentioned notice from the same place, because that logged value clearly can't be an integer ...

Comment: None of this makes any sense, but maybe you've just explained it badly. After `$token=json_decode($AccessToken);`, please put `var_dump($token);` and tell us what you see as the output from that.

Comment: _"i get the output of token and also the error as explained"_ - but it is simply impossible, that you get that from one and the same execution. The notice is saying that you _can't_ access `$token['access_token']`- because $token itself is an integer at this point. But if it _is_ an integer - then the debug output can't possibly be, what you have shown. Logical conclusion: Your code executes more than once.

Comment: the output is correct withe token but i cant access the data and i dont know why it comes back as an int

Comment: We didn't say we didn't like the output, we said your description was unclear and made no sense, which it doesn't. Lack of clarity is a valid reason for downvoting. Please provide the var_dump output as requested above, then it might be easier to see whats really happening. We'd like to help you if we can, but we need you to give us more/better information.

Comment: i added more information or tried to make it clearer. I am not holding information back but there is a few fuctions to get the jwt but the issue is just extracting from the string

Comment: `we have debug not var_dump`...var_dump works in every type of PHP. Please use it, as we requested. I'm not sure what `debug` does, but at a guess it might be turning your data back into a JSON string before it displays it. Why? Because `json_decode` does not output strings, so `$token` still being a JSON string does not make sense.

Comment: It would also be sensible to do `var_dump($AccessToken);` then we can see what the raw data is that you're actually trying to decode.

Comment: That doesn't look like regular var_dump output. e.g. if you had that string response from the raw cURL request, and dumped that, and then decoded it and dumped the decoded object, you'd get this - demo: https://3v4l.org/jZRov . So it's unclear how those `int(1) ` and `bool(true)` bits got there - they aren't relevant to the rest of it, and in a var_dump the data type statement is always at the start, not the end. Are they artifacts from some other output? You don't seem to have constructed a [mre] for us of the output you're showing.

Comment: Upvotes are given for a question being useful and clear. Since the contents of it still don't appear to to make sense - the output you're showing cannot have been generated by the code you're claiming to have used (as my demo proves), it isn't clear, and wouldn't therefore be much use to anyone else. So IMHO it doesn't need an upvote, sorry. AFAIK the makers of cakePHP have not modified the var_dump function. It can't have output what you're saying it did, in the format you've displayed here. Again, you need to provide a [mre] of the scenario to make for a useful question.

Comment: i have provided a minimal function to see the return value in CURL i used in cakephp

Comment: So not your whole source code no, but sufficient code which would provably output what you're showing. One way to ensure that, is to split off your code and make a new script just containing the bits you want to show us, and run that, and see that it produces the output you're talking about. If it doesn't, then you have to modify it until it does. Often, this process actually helps people to narrow down the source of their issue and fix it anyway themselves.

Comment: `i have provided a minimal function to see the return value in CURL i used in cakephp`...I realise you believe that, but again, it's **impossible** for `var_dump` to output the content you showed, in the format you showed, and also impossible for the other code (in the previous version of your post) to generate the error you mentioned, based on what you claimed the content of those variables is. So it makes no sense. There **must** be some other factor in play.

Comment: It is not impossible to output what i have done . You are not understandung this. The type are coming back not as string so save the data to a text type and reload it. Typecast isnt working. I have a solution which works as below. Providing a time consuming example with secret/clientid for the untrusting public is not wise in this case. Its a datatype issue

Comment: `The type are coming back not as string`...but those strings can't be ints or bools, that's physically impossible - you can't put that kind of data into an int. So again, what you show in the supposed var_dump output makes no sense at all. **And** I've already **proved** in my [demo](https://3v4l.org/jZRov) that, if the cURL request returns that JSON (which it makes sense that it would), then dumping the raw string, and then dumping the decoded object, would produce something different than what you're claiming. Did you look at that?

Comment: Your solution is unclear too, as the code shown is not shown in context as to how it relates to the original code - how do they fit together? Saving something into a database field doesn't suddenly make it a valid, decodable string...you would get out of the databsse the exact same thing as you had put into it - so therefore the original must be decodable too. Maybe you should show us how you're saving it too, as that would give more context. And might give a clue as to whether you're somehow treating the data differently than in what you're showing above.

Comment: I have to add yes the data string returned and var_dump is what I got. I got a returned int/bool. I suspect cakephp is making a mistake and hence the need to save it to a DB under a text field. My output has not been tampered with

Answer (score 1):

In the function to send Curl you need to add curlopt_returntransfer as this allows a string tobe returned and not an integer

```
private function CreateAccessToken($jwt)
........
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //ADD
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Then just access the token

```
In cakephp

$AccessToken = $this->CreateAccessToken($jwt);
$token=json_decode($AccessToken);


debug($token->access_token);
//this works as i can access the access token field
```